# SSRS - I want to insert blank rows in tablix control

Tags: reporting-services

I want to create blank rows in tablix control based on dataset column values.

ex. |col1,col2,col3 |
      1   A    3 |
      2   B    2 |
      3   C    5 |

My tablix should display report like this 
     col1, col2 
    | 1       A
     --------- (Blank rows)
     ---------
     ---------|
     2       B
     ---------
     --------- |

Like this i Have to create blank rows in tablix based on column value. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a row grouping on col1 (or any unique/pkey col) and then right click on tablix row and add a row inside group below ... you can merge the inserted row according to your use/requirement

[image]

Based on your requirement.. you have to create a separate report bind that to result set of stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETNUMNER(@N AS INT)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE   @Numbers TABLE
      ( 
             Number INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
      ) 

      WHILE COALESCE(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 0) < @N 
      BEGIN 
             INSERT @Numbers DEFAULT VALUES 
      END   
      SELECT * FROM @Numbers
END
```

this report should have one integer type parameter... take a tablix with empty row (number of columns as per requirement)

now go back to original report.. insert a subreport in empty row (inserted inside group) set the subreport which create with empty tablix.. pass the parameter information  from col3.

what it will do when col3 has value 3.. subreport will generate 3 empty rows & so on.. 
I hope you understand the way i tried to explain.

Comment: Thank you Naveen, I am able create one blank row for each record. But I want to create blank rows based on col3 values. if col3 has 3 then 3 blank rows after first record and col3 has 2 then 2 blank rows after second records.?

Comment: I changed the answer based on your requirement... create a sub report to achieve this